# How to send request body for DELETE in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

So I am trying to send a request body for DELETE in [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I know by default,DRF doesn't support bulk operations so I am using [django-rest-framework-bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk).

Now as per the [tutorial](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk#notes), I am making sure the bulk deletes are allowed only when the query is filtered.I am using BulkModelViewset.

Consider this json array:

```
[{

    "id": "1",
    "first_name": "bruce",
    "second_name": "banner",
    "team": "avengers"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "first_name": "clark",
    "second_name": "kent",
    "team": "Justice League"
}
{

    "id": "3",
    "first_name": "dead",
    "second_name": "pool",
    "team": "x force"
}]
```

Now the I could delete in bulk by passing a filter like :

```
DELETE /api_name/?first_name=bruce,clark
```

But my frontend people want to send a request body because if there are 100 objects which are needed to be deleted, they are not expected to send 100 ids as comma separated string in query parameter.

Is there a way I could send a request body to be deleted like I do in POST,PUT,etc. Like,

```
[{

    "id": "1",
    "first_name": "bruce",
    "second_name": "banner",
    "team": "avengers"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "first_name": "clark",
    "second_name": "kent",
    "team": "Justice League"
}]
```

and the passed objects would be deleted.

I am new to REST principles so there could be fault in my entire logic. I tried to find answers online but couldn't find something specific.Thanks

Sample Viewset:

```
class TeamViewSet(BulkModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TeamViewSerializer
    queryset = TeamView.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class =TeamViewFilter
    ordering = ('id','second_name','first_name','team')

    def allow_bulk_destroy(self, qs, filtered):
        return filtered
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for customizing this logic:

1. Using `APIView` Link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/
2. Using `ViewSet` Link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions

I suggest to go for second one and override `destroy` method of the viewset. Otherwise, if you want to go with the first option, you should override `delete` method.

Examples from the documentation:

1.

```py
    class UserViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Example empty viewset demonstrating the standard
    actions that will be handled by a router class.

    If you're using format suffixes, make sure to also include
    the `format=None` keyword argument for each action.
    """

    def list(self, request):
        pass

    def create(self, request):
        pass

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
    

    # THIS ONE SHOULD BE OVERRIDED
    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

2. ```py
   class SnippetDetail(APIView):
     """
     Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
     """
     def get_object(self, pk):
         try:
             return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
         except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
             raise Http404

     def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
         snippet = self.get_object(pk)
         serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
         return Response(serializer.data)

     def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
         snippet = self.get_object(pk)
         serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
         if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data)
         return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


     # THIS ONE SHOULD BE OVERRIDED
     def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
         snippet = self.get_object(pk)
         snippet.delete()
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
   ```